# SSL Certificates from Webservice

Tags: web-services, ssl, iis, certificate, client

Our company PC machines are connecting to an internal server where a webservice hosted on it further connects to an external webservice in Italy. The certificate provided by the company in Italy to us only has client authentication purposes (thus not allowing us to import the certificate in IIS, right?). From a console application connecting directly to Italy's webservice, the certificate works fine. However the same logic fails when Italy's webservice is requested **through our webservice**.

Could this be because of the missing **server authentication** purpose in the certificate?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: You need to install this certificate to the proper store on the IIS server. What's the application pool identity for this web application?

Comment: There is no 'server authentication' attribute in certificates. please, post the error and the used code

Comment: @Lex Li - I have installed the certificate on the IIS server under Local Machine/Personal with the corresponding CA under the Trusted Authorities keystore. The Application pool identity is applicationpoolidentity and the private keys in MMC have been given Everyone rights.

Comment: The certificate seems to be good, if it has client authentication purpose (no need for server authentication). Can you try to use Network Service as pool identity and try again?

Comment: @LexLi - I used Network Service and didn't work. Actually to be honest, this used to work flawlessly before the cert expired at the providers. Before we had one certificate with Server and Client authentication. Now its just client authentication. Not sure if this difference makes the difference or I am missing something. I changed the cert from MMC (same place as one before) and just changed the distinguished name from the web.config to the new one. Keeps saying could not establish secure connection over....